# Qt5 QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP doesn't work with tr()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

The  [Qt translation documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-qt-tr-noop-and-qt-translate-noop-in-c) states that you can use the `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` macro for strings that are going to be translated via both `tr()` and `QApplication::translate()`, e.g.:

```
static const char* HelloStr = QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("MyClass", "Hello World");

void MyClass::helloWorld()
{
    qDebug() << tr(HelloStr);
    qDebug() << QApplication::translate("MyClass", HelloStr);
}
```

As far as I understood, I just have to make sure that the context given to `QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP` is the same as the class name that calls the `tr()`function. But when running this code, I get the following output:

```
Hello World
Hallo Welt
```

Only the second version, using `QApplication::translate()` does work. Does anybody know why the first version doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you don't know how to reduce your problem to a minimal reproducible example. This is important because doing so you may find something wrong in your code yourself, or facilitate that others can diagnose it comfortably.

For instance, you don't provide a complete definition of `MyClass`. Being `tr()` a member of `QObject`, I suppose that `MyClass` inherits directly or indirectly from `QObject`, but maybe you forgot something in the process. Another possibility is that you used `Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS(MyClass)` and `MyClass` so it does not need to be a subclass of `QObject`?

Anyway, I've tested both options and it worked for me with no error. Here is my minimal example. You need to run `lrelease` to create "i18n_es.qm" that should be copied to the output directory.

test.pro

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11 console
SOURCES += main.cpp
TRANSLATIONS += i18n_es.ts
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTranslator>
#include <QDebug>

static const char* HelloStr = QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("MyClass", "Hello World");

class MyClass
{
    Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS(MyClass)
public:
    void helloWorld() {
        qDebug() << tr(HelloStr);
        qDebug() << QCoreApplication::translate("MyClass", HelloStr);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    qDebug() << "loaded translations ?" << translator.load("i18n_es");
    qDebug() << "installed translator ?" << QCoreApplication::installTranslator(&translator);

    MyClass test;
    test.helloWorld();

    return a.exec();
}
```

i18n_es.ts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.1" language="es_ES">
<context>
    <name>MyClass</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="main.cpp" line="5"/>
        <source>Hello World</source>
        <translation>Hola mundo</translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

output

```
loaded translations ? true
installed translator ? true
"Hola mundo"
"Hola mundo"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I tried your solution and it worked. Unfortunately I already changed a lot of stuff in my original test project so I couldn't reproduce the problem there. But I guess you are right and MyClass wasn't inheriting from QObject...

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-qt-tr-noop-and-qt-translate-noop-in-c) about both macros that:

> They merely mark the text for extraction by the lupdate tool. The macros expand to just the text (without the context).

So, the macros do not directly interfere with tr() or QApplication::translate(). The macros are intended to mark the strings for lupdate to extract them when creating the source .ts files that will be used by lrelease to create .qm translation files.

Comment: Yea you are right, but this doesn't explain why only QApplication::translate() is working... The general process of translation via lupdate and lrelease is working, even for this exact string, as I am using the same string for both versions.

Comment: Both QCoreApplication::translate() and QObject::tr() should work the same. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)